# Get outputs from jq specific line

Tags: shell, aws-cli, jq

The command:

`create_subnet=$(aws ec2 create-subnet --vpc-id "$create_vpc" --cidr-block 10.0.1.0/24   | jq -r '.subnet[].subnetid')`

The output:

```json
"subnet": {

    "availabilityzone": "us-west-1b",
    "availabilityzoneid": "usw1-az3",
    "availableipaddresscount": 251,
    "cidrblock": "10.0.1.0/24",
    "defaultforaz": false,
    "mappubliciponlaunch": false,
    "state": "available",
    "subnetid": "subnet-0745e1611cf09a69a",
    "vpcid": "vpc-07c1508663040cbf7",
    "ownerid": "232856593288",
    "assignipv6addressoncreation": false,
    "ipv6cidrblockassociationset": [],
    "subnetarn": "arn:aws:ec2:us-west-1:232856593288:subnet/subnet-0745e1611cf09a69a",
    "enabledns64": false,
    "ipv6native": false,
    "privatednsnameoptionsonlaunch": {
      "hostnametype": "ip-name",
      "enableresourcenamednsarecord": false,
      "enableresourcenamednsaaaarecord": false
    }
  }
}
```

I need to take the line which is:
subnet-0745e1611cf09a69a
and store it into the variable **create_subnet**

When i execute the script with bash -x i get the follow error:

```
++ jq -r '.subnet[].subnetid'
++ aws ec2 create-subnet --vpc-id vpc-09399bbc31c98efe7 --cidr-block 10.0.1.0/24
jq: error (at <stdin>:24): Cannot iterate over null (null)
```

Maybe i writed the syntax wrong or something like that? I mean for this - **jq -r '.subnet[].subnetid'**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.subnet` is not an array, so the `[]` is not necessary.

```
jq -r '.subnet.subnetid'
```

This works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have missed a { in the first line as your json is not valid without it. It should be something like

{
"subnet": {
"availabilityzone": "us-west-1b",
"availabilityzoneid": "usw1-az3",
"availableipaddresscount": 251,
"cidrblock": "10.0.1.0/24",
"defaultforaz": false,
"mappubliciponlaunch": false,
"state": "available",
"subnetid": "subnet-0745e1611cf09a69a",
"vpcid": "vpc-07c1508663040cbf7",
"ownerid": "232856593288",
"assignipv6addressoncreation": false,
"ipv6cidrblockassociationset": [],
"subnetarn": "arn:aws:ec2:us-west-1:232856593288:subnet/subnet-0745e1611cf09a69a",
"enabledns64": false,
"ipv6native": false,
"privatednsnameoptionsonlaunch": {
"hostnametype": "ip-name",
"enableresourcenamednsarecord": false,
"enableresourcenamednsaaaarecord": false
}
}
}

and use jq -r '.subnet.subnetid' to filter your subnet id